# How to Create Multiple imageview and Get their frames for intersection.?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, cgrect

I am working on game.Below screen shot show the whole process of my Game.
[image]

First of all when my game start,in viewdidload i move  my red ball using NStimer from top to bottom.below when i click on my aeroplan its firs the missels using NStimer...first i check the intersection then create new balls.

```
          if ((CGRectIntersectsRect(missels.frame,Ball.frame))
         {
          [self performSelector:@selector(createball) ];
          }
```

when my missels hit the ball its split into two parts as i show in screen shot.here is code for these two new balls.

```
 -(void)createball{
  imageMove1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,50 ,50)];        
  UIImage *imag = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball1.png"];
  [imageMove1 setImage:imag];
  imageMove1.tag=i;
  [self.view addSubview:imageMove1];
  [ballArray addObject:imageMove1];

  imageMove2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,50 ,50)];        
  UIImage *imag1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball1.png"];
  [imageMove2 setImage:imag1];
  imageMove2.tag=k;
  [self.view addSubview:imageMove2];
  [ball1Array addObject:imageMove2];
  [self performSelector:@selector(moveball) ];
 }
```

after that i give the movement to these new balls using CAKeyframeAnimation .here is code.

```
-(void)moveball{
 for (int i=0; i<[ballArray count]; i++) {
 moveimg=[ballArray objectAtIndex:i];
 CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
 pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
 pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
 pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
 pathAnimation.duration = 15.0;
 pathAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
 CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
 CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, x+15, y);
 CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, 20, 10, 100, 330);
 pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
 CGPathRelease(curvedPath);
 moveimg.center=CGPointMake(x, y);
 [moveimg.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"moveTheSquare"];
  }

for (int k=0; k<[ball1Array count]; k++) {
        move1img=[ball1Array objectAtIndex:k];
        CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation1 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        pathAnimation1.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
        pathAnimation1.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        pathAnimation1.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        pathAnimation1.duration = 15.0;
        pathAnimation1.repeatCount = 1;
        CGMutablePathRef curvedPath1 = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath1, NULL, x+40, y);
        CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(curvedPath1, NULL, 350, 10, 380, 330);
        pathAnimation1.path = curvedPath1;
        CGPathRelease(curvedPath1);
        move1img.center=CGPointMake(x, y);
        [move1img.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation1 forKey:@"moveTheSquare"];
     }
   }
```

My this methods only works for me to create first two balls after missels and ball intersection.once when my balls gets movement after that its not works for intersection.so in short in this games i face two main problems.

1. How to create two new balls on every intersections of my ball and missels.
2. After creation of these balls how to get frames of these balls during movement for intersection with missel.just like this..

   ```
     if ((CGRectIntersectsRect(missels.frame,mynewballs.frame))
   ```

   Any one can give the best idea to solve this problem.any help will be appriated.thanx in advance.

Comment: Exactly like Buster Bro (Pang) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVLyCBwAzIU ?

Comment: @Byte thanx but can u give me the idea about creation of new images.?

Comment: Sorry no. I only commented for 2 reasons. 1) To credit the original creator of the idea which you should have, given the fact that this is pretty much a remake of it. 2.) to help other people get the idea of what you are making, thus helping them help you.